# Format one row as soon as cumulative sum reaches a particular number

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

[image: My Google Sheet]

I have a Google sheet that shows the number of KM a vehicle ran every day. Column E is the total distance. I want to change row background to red as soon as the value in E crosses 1000. And it should apply only to that one immediate row.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select A5 to wherever suits, and apply a Conditional formatting formula rule of:

```
=countif($E$5:$E5,">1000")=1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this directly with a formula from the Conditional Formatting option.

In my example I am shading the row in the area `A1:B3` based on the values in `C`

Use the `format cells if ... custom formula is` option and put the conditions you want you range to change in there.

E.g. I am formatting my range to change to green when `=$C1>=1000`

Notice I don't need to change `C1` to include all the rows, as it will evaluation on every for separately.

[image]